# Are the student solo endorsements a “package deal” with that one specific instructor?

Tags: faa-regulations, student-pilot, logbook-endorsements

If someone receives a student who’s completed his old instructor’s pre written solo exam and received an endorsement, do I need to give him my solo test and endorsement?

**Or** go ahead and complete the flight training/proficiency and 90 day endorsement?

My understanding is that it’s a "package deal", one instructor must do it all. *Except* the XC pre-flight planning preparation endorsement, and this one can be given by any instructor.

Can someone confirm this? With possible quotes from FAR, ACs or interpretations.

Comment: and how would that work with flying schools employing multiple instructors, where a student can receive training from any of them? Sound more like you're looking for an excuse to tag a student with additional cost (to your personal benefit) than anything else. If you don't trust whether the endorsement is valid, that's a reason to investigate. Call the instructor who supposedly issued it for example.

Comment: I was in a similar situation as a student a couple weeks ago. My new instructor just wrote a new endorsement without having me take another pre-solo test.

Answer (score 6):

The FAR's don't talk about whether or not a CFI can accept another instructor's solo endorsement. If the student has the endorsement, the 90 day period has not expired, and the make and model of the aircraft in the endorsement matches, then the student is technically good to go.

That said, a good CFI would carefully review the student's log book and, if necessary, require additional instruction/review before allowing the flight school to rent the student an aircraft. [The relevant FAR is 61.87](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.87).

Comment: I concur. I’ve had students who have solo endorsements from a different instructor, and in need of more solo time. As long as those endorsements are correct and valid (the 90-day one), I’m not required to give any additional endorsements (except for each Solo XC). Once the 90-day period is over, I simply have to give a new 90-day endorsement.

Answer (score 1):

**61.195 Flight instructor limitations and qualifications**

**(d)** ***Limitations on endorsements.*** A flight instructor may not endorse a:

(1) Student pilot's logbook for solo flight privileges, unless that flight instructor has -

(i)Given that student the flight training required for solo flight privileges required by this port; and

(ii) Determined the student is prepared to conduct the flight safely under known circumstances, subject to any limitations listed in the student's logbook that the instructor considers necessary for the safety of the flight.